# Runtime error 70 Permission Denied when 2 programs try to read and write the csv file

Tags: excel, vba, csv, asp.net-mvc-4

I have VBA script in excel which gets triggered when state of the **Worksheet Calculate** takes place in given cells. The script writes data to the csv file. only 20 cells needs to be written to the csv file. The speed at which Worksheet Calculate is triggered = 100ms to 200ms because data is changing quickly almost in real-time.

On the other hand, I have asp.net MVC project which tries to read the same CSV file when api get request is sent.

VBA script executed alone does not lead to any problem. But when I try to read same csv file I see my VBA script gets halt and gives following error: **Runtime error 70 Permission Denied**

I think the reason for this could be **2 programs are trying to access the same csv file concurrently for read/write**.

### VBA Code

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim Target As Range

Dim myFile As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim cellValue As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim count As Integer
Dim xval As Integer
Dim yval As Integer
xval = 6
yval = 8
count = 0

myFile = "C:\Users\test\Desktop\saved.csv"
Set rng = Range("D15:I15")

    If Not Intersect(rng, Range("D15:I15")) Is Nothing Then

        Open myFile For Output As #1
            For i = 1 To yval
                For j = 1 To xval
                    cellValue = rng.Cells(i, j).Value
                    If j = xval Then
                        Write #1, cellValue
                    Else
                        Write #1, cellValue,
                    End If
                Next j
            Next i
        Close #1
    End If
End Sub
```

I found this article : https://varunvns.wordpress.com/2012/05/05/reading-and-writing-in-text-files-with-multiple-programs-accessing-it-simultaneously/

which could be the solution to my problem. **FileShare**. but I am not sure how to set such a flag in VBA Excel when writing as ReadWrite and asp.net code to set a flag as Read when accessing csv file.

Comment: As long as you have your file open for write, what do you expect the reading process to read? The file changes any moment, so it makes no sense to read it - this ***is*** the reason it is locked.

Comment: Make this *"asp.net MVC project which tries to read the same CSV file"* read action open the file in **read-only mode** so it does not affect the writing from VBA. A file can only be opened once at the same time in writing mode, but reading mode is possible multiple times.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I will try this and get back. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your *asp.net MVC project* only needs to read the file then open the file in **read-only mode** so it does not affect the writing from VBA.

A file can only be opened once at the same time in writing mode, but read-only mode is possible multiple times.

Nevertheless I see not much sense in reading a file that changes every 200 ms. If you read the data it is already old.